# ts1219 experimental support for decorators in visual studio 2019

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2019

Ive updated typescript to v4.4.2 and also visual studio 2019 is using 4.4 for intellisense.  Im getting this error message though

'TS1219:experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release.  Set the experimentalDecorator option in your tsconfig or jsconfig to remove this warning'

I dont have a jsconfig, only a tsconfig and its set to 'true'
setting it to false makes no difference.

how do I get rid of this error ?

Comment: Are you using a MonoRepo? In VS Code CMD/CTRL + Shift + P --> `TypeScript: Go to project configuration` and check if vs code can open your tsconfig - if not the structure may be a problem.

Comment: Im using visual studio 2019 profesional